# Calculation of the wind direction from the u and v components of a grib

Tags: python, python-xarray, grib

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# Open GRIB with xarray
data_wind = xr.open_dataset('test.grib', engine='cfgrib')

# Extract wind from grib
u_variable = data_wind['u10']
v_variable = data_wind['v10']

# Convert var 
u = u_variable.values
v = v_variable.values


# Compute wind direction
wind_dir = np.mod(180 + (180/np.pi) * np.arctan2(v, u), 360)
```

Hi,

I'm currently trying to calculate the wind direction at each grid point of a grib. However, with the method I'm currently using, I have no way to be sure that the u and v values used in wind_dir are coming from the same point in space and time...
Does anyone have any idea how I can make sure this is the case ?

thank you in advance

Antoine

I tried to set up a loop that goes through all the points, but without success

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your grib file is constructed correctly, what you are worried about is handled by the magic of `xarray`. It "knows" how to match coordinates and times, and you shouldn't need to worry about it.

In your example, you can look at the output of `u.shape` and `v.shape`. This should give you a three member tuple representing the lat, lon and time steps, which xarray uses to match data across these dimensions. `wind_dir.shape` should give the same result, as it will have the same dimensions as the inputs. If these are not the same you'll get an error in the wind_dir calculation step.

Here's an example you can play with

```
import pandas as pd

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "v": xr.DataArray(
            [
                [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [2.2, 3.3, 4.4], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]],
                [[1.2, 2.3, 3.4], [2.3, 3.4, 4.5], [4.5, 5.6, 6.7]],
            ],
            coords={
                "time": pd.DatetimeIndex(["2023-11-07", "2023-11-08"]),
                "latitude": [-10.25, -11.25, -12.25],
                "longitude": [112.25, 113.25, 114.25],
                    },
            dims=["time", "latitude", "longitude"],
            attrs={"long_name": "some variable"},
        ),
    },
)

# create u variable 
ds["u"] = ds.v

print(ds.v.shape) # (2, 3, 3)
print(ds.u.shape) # (2, 3, 3)

ds.v - ds.u # array of zeros
```

PS. You can slightly simplify the direction calculation like so:

```py
wind_dir = np.degrees(np.arctan2(u, v)) % 360
```